# Customizing the Submissions List View in Wagtail

Tags: django, django-views, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I'm trying to subclass the `SubmissionsListView` for the Wagtail admin. I'm following the instructions from [this tutorial](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/forms/customisation.html?highlight=SubmissionsListView#customise-form-submissions-listing-in-wagtail-admin) and [this one](https://dev.to/lb/image-uploads-in-wagtail-forms-39pl).

Here's my code:

```
class CustomSubmissionsListView(SubmissionsListView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if not self.is_export:
            # generate a list of field types, the first being the injected 'submission date'
            field_types = ['user'] + [field.field_type for field in self.form_page.get_form_fields()]
            data_rows = context['data_rows']

            DocumentModel = get_document_model()

            for data_row in data_rows:

                fields = data_row['fields']

                for idx, (value, field_type) in enumerate(zip(fields, field_types)):
                    if field_type == 'document' and value:
                        doc = DocumentModel.objects.get(pk=value)
                        url = reverse('wagtaildocument:edit', args=(doc.id,))
                        # build up a link to the image, using the image title & id
                        fields[idx] = format_html(
                            "<a href='{}'>{}</a>",
                            url,
                            doc.title,
                            value
                        )

        return context
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
  File "/home/dave/sandbox/clients/devnw/devnw/web/products/models.py", line 161, in get_context_data
if not self.is_export:
    AttributeError: 'CustomSubmissionsListView' object has no attribute 'is_export'
```

I cannot figure out what is going on. The `is_export' does exist on the parent module. Any pointers?

Comment: What version of Wagtail are you running? The `is_export` flag was introduced in Wagtail 2.9.

Comment: that cleared that up! Thanks for the heads up.